# How do I get an .mp3's Album/Artist data?

Tags: vb.net, mp3, audio-player

I am trying to get the Album data and Artist data from a .mp3 file. Here is my code I am trying to use, but it always returns blank:

```
miniMusic.currentMedia.getItemInfo("Artist")
```

When I use that property for my application in the way of:

```
Label1.Text = miniMusic.currentMedia.getItemInfo("Artist")
```

It returns blank. I made sure it was the actual returning data that was blank by doing:

```
Label1.Text = "Artist: " + miniMusic.currentMedia.getItemInfo("Artist")
```

To see the label's text only say "Artist: " when I invoked that code.

How can I obtain the song file's data and display it in my application?

The only data I was able to display was the title information from the `"currentMedia.getItemInfo("Title")`

I made my own .mp3 file in Audacity and made sure to include the artist name (John) and album title (Laffin' on sunshine (Not a real album!) and my application still cannot find this data. Am I doing it incorrectly or is the media control unable to find this data?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider reading the ID3 tags independently from the media control.

[This SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+id3) yields choices of free libraries that will do the grunt work for you. Here are two.

- [Taglib sharp](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html) (C#)
- [UltraID3Lib](http://home.fuse.net/honnert/UltraID3Lib/) (VB.NET)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a very well documentation for that, or my blindness is acting up. Care to give a small example on how to get that information? :-)